# HTTP Headers Information to show XML file

Tags: php, http-headers

I want to show XML file on my page, I have set the header `header('Content-Type: application/xml')`also tried for `header(application/rss+xml)`,
but my URL can not show the page in XML format but in View Page Source it created the XML file

URL- http://submitsitelink.com/rss.php?p=d

Can you please help me ?

Thanks

Comment: looks fine in firefox, you really should put line breaks within your code so it looks nice ;0

Comment: If you tring to make rss, its working

Comment: have you tried `header('Content-type: text/xml');`

Comment: Do you want the browser to output the RSS nicely? - Not all browsers do that, and you can't force them to do it. - If you're trying to make an RSS feed, it's already working.

Comment: I am checking code in Chrome browser it show in text format

Comment: I guess you are seeing it in opera?

Comment: It seems to work on Android too.

Comment: It is a known bug for chrome for quite a time.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome can neither read RSS nor beautify XML natively. You have to find and install an extension:

- [RSS Subscription Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd)
- [XML Tree](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbammbheopgpmaagmckhpjbfgdfkpadb)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to style the output of your XML - one method of doing this is via [XSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL) technologies. You can also [add CSS stylesheets to XML documents](http://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML.en.html) by adding something akin to the following near the top of your XML document.

`<?xml-stylesheet href="common.css"?>`

As far as I know you cannot do this with HTTP headers, only by modifying the XML document itself.